# Name recursively created dataframes with values from a set

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following set:

```
set_1 = {'adam', 'barbara', 'carl', 'daniel', 'earl'}
```

I would like to create five dataframes, one named after each set entry. As an example, we can use the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)))
```

Comment: `DataFrame`s don't have the concept of having a name.  Unless you are talking about variable names, in which case you just want a `dict` of `str` to `DataFrame`.

Answer (score 1):

- You will need to create a dict of dataframes

  - Each value in `set_1` will be a key in the dictionary.

```py
df_dict = dict()
for name in set_1:
    df_dict[name] = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)))
```

- This can be done with a list-comprehension, but not if you also have other things to do while building the dataframe.

```py
df_dict = {k: pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4))) for k in set_1}
```